# Registering a Custom Data Module in Delphi (XE)

Tags: delphi

I'm want to add a published property to a DataModule in Delphi XE such that the property shows in the object inspector. I am across the basic details but am stuck at the point where I need to register the custom module (in a design-time package). All of the help  that I can find seems to refer to older versions of Delphi.

I believe I need a line like this below in the Register procedure:

RegisterCustomModule(TMyForm , TDataModuleDesignerCustomModule);

However, the correct value for the second parameter of type TCustomModuleClass eludes me.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think anything significant has changed. Everything that Marco says here: http://www.marcocantu.com/ddh/ddh15/ddh15e.htm is still valid I believe. The second parameter is your class that is derived from `TCustomModule`, or a sub-class of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want to do is to have published properties show up in the `Object Inspector`, then as I understand from [Marco's book](http://www.marcocantu.com/ddh/ddh15/ddh15e.htm), you can pass `TCustomModule` as the custom module class. It will surface all published properties.

Comment: David: That appears to have done the trick. Thanks a million for your prompt reply. And thanks for your numerous detailed and helpful replies elsewhere. Where do I get a fan club registration form? Cheers.

Comment: Glad it worked. I've never done anything with custom modules not to mention data modules so I'm happy that I seem to have correctly interpreted Marco's words.

Answer (score 2):

Complete example and steps to create a package containing these custom registration types:

```
unit YourCustomTypesReg;

interface

procedure Register;

implementation

uses
  DesignIntf,
  DesignEditors,
  YourUnit1,YourUnit2,YourUnit3;

type
   TCustomDataModule = TCustomModule;

procedure Register;
begin
   RegisterCustomModule (TYourClass1, TCustomDataModule );
   RegisterCustomModule (TYourClass2, TCustomDataModule );
   RegisterCustomModule( TYourClass3, TCustomDataModule );
end;

end.
```

Add to a new or existing Package, if it's a new package, remember to change type of Package to Designtime only, add reference to designide.dcp, so that DesignIntf and DesignEditors units will be found.

You may need to add VCL to the Unit Scope Names to get your new package to compile.

You may also need to set the Package and DCP and DCU output folders to something other than blank, and other than any other package or application so the dcus generated by this package don't interfere with anybody else's package.